# Add new elements to the top of the list

Tags: javascript, html, list

I am kind of stuck. I have thought of the idea to use the .insertBefore() but I am not sure where to place the syntax. I also need to add checkboxes instead of the bullets that automaticly apear when using , I have no clue have to do this.
My code is as follows.
HTML

```js
const n = [];

function changeText() {
  inputText = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
  n.push(inputText);

  document.querySelector('#list ul').innerHTML += "<li>" + inputText 
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>To-Do list</title>
        <mmeta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="todoStyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="form">
            <h1>New Task</h1>
            <div id="button">
                <button onclick="changeText()">Add to list</button>
            </div>
            <div id="input">
                <input type="text" id="inputText" name="addNewList">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list1" id="list">
            <h1>My to-do list</h1>
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="todo.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried inserting the .insertBefore() in a new document.getElementById. But I was not sure where to insert this line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `afterbegin`, I used css to remove the circle of the list styles and having a checkbox with the text, now you should have some events for the input to handle.

```js
const n = [];

function changeText() {
  inputText = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
  n.push(inputText)
  // get reference to the nav tag
  const listUl = document.querySelector("#list ul");
  listUl.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", `
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox"/>  
    ${inputText}
  </li>
  `);
}
```

```css
#list ul li{
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>To-Do list</title>
        <mmeta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="todoStyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="form">
            <h1>New Task</h1>
            <div id="button">
                <button onclick="changeText()">Add to list</button>
            </div>
            <div id="input">
                <input type="text" id="inputText" name="addNewList">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list1" id="list">
            <h1>My to-do list</h1>
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="todo.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add an element to the beginning of an array, just array.unshift(element) instead of .push

And for putting a checkbox per array item:

```
<li><input type="checkbox"/></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to first save the current content. Then you will concatenate the new item with the current content, in the order you want it to be presented. I modified the code to work like that

```js
const n = [];

function changeText() {
  inputText = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
  // add the item in the beginning of the list
  n.unshift(inputText);

  // save current listing
  const currentContent = document.querySelector('#list ul').innerHTML;

  // append new item in the beginning the the current listing
  document.querySelector('#list ul').innerHTML = "<li>" + inputText + "</li>" + currentContent;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>To-Do list</title>
        <mmeta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="todoStyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="form">
            <h1>New Task</h1>
            <div id="button">
                <button onclick="changeText()">Add to list</button>
            </div>
            <div id="input">
                <input type="text" id="inputText" name="addNewList">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list1" id="list">
            <h1>My to-do list</h1>
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="todo.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```